# Is it compulsory to go through Microsoft sign in page when Django app is integrating with Azure Active Directory?

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-active-directory, integration

I have integrated my Django app with Azure Active Directory using [`django-auth-adfs` library](https://django-auth-adfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). My app perfectly signs in and out through Django app. The main issue is I have to go through Microsoft sign in page every time, so my question is:

Is it compulsory to go through Microsoft page or we can do authentication using my Django sign in page but authentication should be from Microsoft?

Please provide the detailed document or information if we can do this without using Microsoft sign in page.

Answer (score 0):

Sign in definetly takes you to your microsoft login page but if you want the login which shows your app logos or background , you can customize the sign in using company branding .

> Cloud applications can use OpenID Connect, OAuth, SAML,
> password-based, linked, or disabled methods for single sign-on.

### Choose any of the Single sign on methods for authentication

- Choose password-based SSO when an application authenticates with a
  username and password instead of access tokens and headers You may
  Refer -> [Password-Based-SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-password-based-sso)

(or)

- Set up SAML-based single sign-on (SSO) for an application in your
  Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant .

References:  **1)** [Configure SAML single sign on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-saml-single-sign-on#basic-saml-configuration)   **2)** [portal setup-sso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal-setup-sso)

**You may then customize the login page logo for your application which
is microsoft account login but represents your app.**

- You can customize your Azure AD sign-in pages, which appear when
  users sign in to your organization's tenant-specific apps:

Refer:
[Cutomize-Branding-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding) -->
[tutorial for customizing brand.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxqTk3TPoAo)

[image]

---

- When auth-code-flow or implicit-grant-flow is used, users will be
  redirected to the sign-in page, but when using
  client-creds-grant-flow or ropc flow, an api call can directly be
  made to the /token endpoint of Azure AD to acquire a token.

> If one is using OIDC and want to sign-in and get ID token first,
> users will have to go through the sign-in page. Afterwards, they can
> use one of the oauth flows mentioned below to acquire access token.

References:

1. [auth-code-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)
2. [implicit-grant-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow)
3. [client-creds-grant-flow](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)
4. [oauth-ropc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)